# asp.net 0:T decimal places using dataformatstring="{0:T}"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a race time that I want to display as `hh:mm:ss.00`

It is stored in sql database as `time(7)` and displayed in an asp.net datagrid using `dataformatstring="{0:T}"`.

This gives me `00:08:21.6000000`. I want to display this as `00:08:21.60`

Can anyone advise how I can restrict the number of digits displayed for the fractions of a second? Can I do this using dataformatstring or will I have to handle it in the code (C#)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datetime format as below

```
dataformatstring ="{0:HH:mm:ss.ff}"
```

Check for different options
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ffSpecifier

Comment: I did try that but it throws an error. I am using data type time(7) to store the time and it appears in the sql db table as e.g. 03:56:01.6000000

Input string was not in a correct format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Get your time from SQL Query in desired Format as:

```
  SELECT CAST(CONVERT(TIME(2),'00:08:21.6000000') AS VARCHAR(15))
```

And Its OutPut Will be:

```
00:08:21.60
```